# Is GCP user or GCP employee able to use Service Agents?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

**is this possible for me, bad actor or GCP employee to use/impersonate an Service Agent?**

I'm digging around security of Service Accounts and Service Agents.
When new API is being enabled, Service Agent is being created under the hood, which usually is being assigned with a role named *"... Service Agent"*, which is containing *iam.serviceAccounts.actAs*. Potentially this role would allow an bad actor to impersonate Service Account which no normal user or SAccount can impersonate (because of lack of permissions to the SAccount) through Service Agent (because SAgent gets project level *iam.serviceAccounts.actAs*, which is giving access to all SAccounts in the entire project).

I have not found any info in documentation if Service Agents can be impersonated/used like Service Accounts by actors/Service Accounts. Closest was [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65119679/22214643) which implies SAgents are for the runtime. But for the runtime only? :)

**Edit #1:**
Allow me to add example from my comment:

Service Account #1 or User impersonates Service Agent and then this Service Agent impersonates more powerful Service Account #2

Comment: I wrote the answer you reference. I have not tried to impersonate a Service Agent. However, if a user is granted permission to impersonate another service account, they can impersonate normal service accounts. Some of those have elevated permissions (Compute Engine for example). Therefore your problem is not if they can impersonate a Serice Agent, but if they can impersonate any service account. You need policies to manage the permissions user have and the permissions they can assume via impersonation. You can take that further with permission monitoring and alerting.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the answer. I know that Service Agent can impersonate Service Account (otherwise this permission ActAs would be ridiculous), but is someone able to use that (Service Account #1 or User impersonates Service Agent and then this Service Agent impersonates more powerful Service Account #2). Other normal use cases were user impersonates SAccounts are not important.